# Foreign key constraint on sub-column of composite-type column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, composite-types

Is there any way to set a sub-column of a composite type column as a foreign key?

What I have tried is:

```
Create Type info_typ_ AS (
  category integer ,
  title text ,
  actor text ,
  price double precision );

Create Table Products_typobj (
prod_id integer,
info info_typ_,
primary key(prod_id),
Category references Categories(Category)
);
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me

```
Create Type info_typ_ AS (
  category integer ,
  title text ,
  actor text ,
  price double precision );

Create Table Products_typobj (
prod_id integer,
info info_typ_,
primary key(prod_id)
);
```

I removed line with `references`, so using `type` works.
**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/9a9a9/2/0)**

If you need foreign key, try below code:

```
Create Type info_typ_ AS (
  category integer ,
  title text ,
  actor text ,
  price double precision );

Create Table Categories (
  Category int,
  primary key(Category)
);  

Create Table Products_typobj (
prod_id integer,
info info_typ_,
Category int references Categories(Category),  
primary key(prod_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Category) REFERENCES Categories (Category)
);
```

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/25acc/1/0)**

Comment: `category` will be in both the `info_typ` and `categories` ?

Comment: You don't need category in info_typ_.

Comment: That's actually a work-around with an alternative table-design. Referencing an element of a composite type in a foreign key is *not possible* AFAIC.